Image Slider Isn't Displaying
I've got an image slider that works as desired on every browser except for Safari and Mozilla Firefox. The image slider won't display on these two browsers.
If I remove the overflow: hidden; line in the CSS, the image slider shows up on Safari and Mozilla Firefox. However, when this code is removed it displays incorrectly.
I've also tried switching the height on .slider from % to vh. It then displays on Safari and Mozilla Firefox, but the buttons (circular dots) on the bottom of the image slider don't display properly and there is a space between the slider and the images below it.
Any advice would be much appreciated.


var count = 1;
setInterval(function() {

  document.getElementById('radio-button' + count).checked = true;

  count++;
  if (count > 5) {
    count = 1;
  }

}, 5000);
.slider {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.slides {
  width: 500%;
  display: flex;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide {
  width: 20%;
  transition: 2s;
}

.slide img {
  width: 100%;
}

.slide-manual {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.manual-button {
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 1s;
  margin: 15px;
}

.manual-button:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

#radio-button1:checked~.one {
  margin-left: 0;
}

#radio-button2:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -20%;
}

#radio-button3:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -40%;
}

#radio-button4:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -60%;
}

#radio-button5:checked~.one {
  margin-left: -80%;
}

.slide-automatic {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 0%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.slide-automatic div {
  border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  transition: 1S;
  margin: 15px;
}

#radio-button1:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button1,
#radio-button2:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button2,
#radio-button3:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button3,
#radio-button4:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button4,
#radio-button5:checked~.slide-automatic .auto-button5 {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}
<div class="slider">

  <div class="slides">

    <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button1">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button2">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button3">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button4">
    <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="radio-button5">


    <div class="slide one">
      <a href="Blogs/Travel/JapanTravel_English.html"><img loading="lazy" src="Blogs/Home_Page/Slideshow/Japan_Travel/Travel_Home_Page_English.jpg" alt="Sighseeing, Japan"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <a href="Blogs/Travel/Kansai/Kyoto/Heian_Shrine_Shinen/Heian_Shrine_Shinen_English.html"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" alt="Heian Shrine Shinen, Japanese garden, Garden, Heian shrine, Shrine, Shinto, Kyoto, Kyoto prefecture, Japan"></a>
    </div>

<div class="slide">
      <a href="Blogs/Travel/Kanto/Tokyo/Koizumu_Yakumo_Kinen_Koen/Koizumi_Yakumo_Kinen_Koen_English.html"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" alt="Koizumu Yakumo Commemorative Park, Park, Koizumi Yakumo, Commemorative Park, Lafcadio Hearn, Tokyo Metropolis, Tokyo, Japan"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <a href="Blogs/Culture/Pop_Culture/Blog/Japanese_Comics_Cartoons/Japanese_Comics_Cartoons_English.html"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" alt="Comic Books, Comics, Cartoon, Cartoons, Japan, Japanese"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <a href="Blogs/Travel/Kanto/Kanagawa/Hakone/Hakone_Shrine/Hakone_Shrine_English.html"><img loading="lazy" src="https://picsum.photos/800/600" alt="Hakone Shrine, Shrine, Shinto, Hakone, Kanagawa prefecture, Kanagawa, Japan"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="slide-automatic">
      <div class="auto-button1"></div>
      <div class="auto-button2"></div>
      <div class="auto-button3"></div>
      <div class="auto-button4"></div>
      <div class="auto-button5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="slide-manual">
    <label for="radio-button1" class="manual-button"></label>
    <label for="radio-button2" class="manual-button"></label>
    <label for="radio-button3" class="manual-button"></label>
    <label for="radio-button4" class="manual-button"></label>
    <label for="radio-button5" class="manual-button"></label>
  </div>
</div>




There seems to be an issue with the 'overflow: hidden' tag I'm using in my CSS. If I get rid of it then the slider will show up in Safari and Firefox but displays incorrectly.

The height of .slider (100%) is relative to it's parent, in this case body, but body doesn't has any height (by default). See duped question

From your edit: Questions should focus on one problem at the time... You just changed the entire question to something else

I agree with DarkBee, simply changing height: 100%; to height: 100vh; seems to solve the invisibility problem. It, by the way, also didn't show in Chrome.

I added height: 100vh; to the .body CSS. The image slider now displays properly on all browsers.
